# Partitioned table - is adding an index on the partition column unnecessary?

Tags: postgresql

We have a table partitioned on a date column.

Some of my colleagues believe that this means that column is automatically indexed. Having looked for evidence of this I don't believe that is so. Who is right?

The manual https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html (section 5.11.2.1. Example) says:

> Create an index on the key column(s), as well as any other indexes you
> might want, on the partitioned table. (The key index is not strictly
> necessary, but in most scenarios it is helpful.) This automatically
> creates a matching index on each partition, and any partitions you
> create or attach later will also have such an index. An index or
> unique constraint declared on a partitioned table is “virtual” in the
> same way that the partitioned table is: the actual data is in child
> indexes on the individual partition tables.

This suggests to me we should create the index.

Each partition has ~350K rows. Since we often query by date range on that column would each partition get its own index? Or one massive one across all partitions?

Would adding an index on this column improve or degrade performance?

Comment: each partition will have personal index. sadly, postgres doesn't support of global indexes (which are very useful to ensure real uniqueness).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure I understand how a global index could ensure uniqueness. Wouldn't that happen anyway if each partition had its own unique index? Also, if you were querying on a narrow date range what would be the advantage of a global index? Wouldn't smaller indexes on each partition be faster?

Comment: imagine you have a table "unique_things(thing_id numeric, some_date date) partition by range (some_date)". in postgres it means that you can't create unique index _only_ on "thing_id" field. instead you must create composite unique index on "(thing_id, some_date)", which (obvious) don't provides _real_ uniqueness of "thing_id" field. it was just N of local unique _composite_ indexes. if you _must_ guaranteed "thing_id" deduplication then you have a problem that cannot be easily solved with postgres (unlike oracle for example, because of oracle _supports_ global indexes on partitioned tables).

Comment: in terms of r\w speed global indexes is a tradeoff, because them impacts on write speed in essence. we add partitioning to decrease r\w concurrency, but global indexes is global and will be a hotspot. it takes a lot of time to explain how to eliminate global indexing impact on write speed, but it's totally out of postgres context because of lack of that technology in postgres :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not automatically an index on the partition column.

If you did list partitioning and every list only contains one date (i.e. every date has its own partition) then I don't think also having an index on that column would be helpful.  There is not extra information in the column beyond what the partitioning already knows about.

If you did range partitioning on quarter or year, but often query by a specific date, then the index would likely be useful as it provides a lot of extra specificity.

Comment: "If you did range partitioning on quarter or year, but often query by a specific date, then the index would likely be useful as it provides a lot of extra specificity." Yes, that's precisely our use case except we partition by month not quarter. Thanks for the response.